# Derived direct image of emdedding of projective varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, derived-functors

Let $i:Y\to X$ be an embedding map between projective varieties. What is the example of $X$ and $Y$ such that the functor $Ri_*:D^b(\text{Coh}\,Y)\to D^b(\text{Coh}\,X)$ is not a fully faithful embedding? What about when $Y$ is the curve?

Comment: I think a degree d divisor in projective space should already do the trick. However, it is always injective on $\mathrm{Ext}^0$ and $\mathrm{Ext}^1$, in higher $\mathrm{Ext}^*$ everything is up for grabs though. However it will be very very rarely surjective as already in the case of any degree d hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^{>1}$ you will get higher ext groups as $\mathrm{Ext}^*(\mathrm{R}f_*F,\mathrm{R}f_* F)\cong \mathrm{Ext}^*(\mathrm{L}f^*\mathrm{R}f_* F)\cong \mathrm{Ext}^*(F,F)\oplus \mathrm{Ext}^{*-1}(F(d),F)$.